# Getting the source of a specific image element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have many image elements and want to get a specific image's source where the alternative text is *"example"*.

I tried this:

```
var src = $('.conversation_img').attr('src');
```

but I can't get the one I need with that.

How do I select a specific image element based on its alternative text?

Comment: Any error message you received.?

Comment: no im getting first element i dont know element position i only know alt text

Comment: Working here man demo :) - http://jsfiddle.net/yL5cf/1/

Answer (score 55, accepted):

To select and element where you know only the attribute value you can use the below jQuery script

```
var src = $('.conversation_img[alt="example"]').attr('src');
```

Please refer the [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) for attribute equals selectors

Please also refer to the example in [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SCqQg/)

Following is the code incase you are not able to access the demo..

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img alt="example" src="\images\show.jpg" />
    <img  alt="exampleAll" src="\images\showAll.jpg" />  

</div>
```

**SCRIPT JQUERY**

```
var src = $('img[alt="example"]').attr('src');
alert("source of image with alternate text = example - " + src);


var srcAll = $('img[alt="exampleAll"]').attr('src');
alert("source of image with alternate text = exampleAll - " + srcAll );
```

**Output will be**

Two Alert messages each having values

1. source of image with alternate text = example - \images\show.jpg
2. source of image with alternate text = exampleAll -
   \images\showAll.jpg

Comment: it should be this bro: `var src = $('img.conversation_img[alt="example"]').attr('src');` because single quotes within single quotes will not work, cheerios!

Comment: you're not escaping `example` and there for an error will occur

Answer (score 7):

```
$('img.conversation_img[alt="example"]')
    .each(function(){
         alert($(this).attr('src'))
    });
```

This will display src attributes of all images of class 'conversation_img' with alt='example'

Answer (score 2):

```
var src = $('img.conversation_img[alt="example"]').attr('src');
```

If you have multiple matching elements only the src of the first one will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specifically need the alt text of an image, then you can just target the class/id of the image.

```
$('img.propImg').each(function(){ 
     enter code here
}
```

I know it’s not quite answering the question, though I’d spent ages trying to figure this out and this question gave me the solution :). In my case I needed to hide any image tags with a specific src.

```
$('img.propImg').each(function(){ //for each loop that gets all the images. 
        if($(this).attr('src') == "img/{{images}}") { // if the src matches this
        $(this).css("display", "none") // hide the image.
    }
});
```